# Tracking bash history when many users logging in using one user account

Tags: linux

I'm using the system to which many users will login thru common auth method to the system as one common user and execute any commands from that user id.. Common auth method stores the logged in session details in a file like which user logged in with timeformat.

Now I want to track which individual user is logging to that common user and what commands they are executing

Is there a way?

Comment: Can you prevent two users to be logged in at the same time?

Comment: @xenoid I don't think. we have many users they may login at same time

Comment: So you will have audit records telling you that some id did something but you may not have the session information telling which real user that was. But frankly, your scheme is flawed. If you want a meaningful audit of what your people do, you have to give them different ids. And tracking bash commands won't get you far,  there are plenty of ways to circumvent that. Don't try to invent your own scheme, see what informed people are doing. See unix.stackexchange.com and/or security.stackexchange.com.